# PIR sensor with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

My project is to take the reading from the PIR sensor and play a song when the person is in front of the sensor but I cannot figure the logic behind this code that I found online and tried modifying it.

What I need to do is:

1. How do I loop this, omxp.poll() doesn't work :(

Edit: Now It stops but is there a way to loop the process and is there a way to make the script memory efficient

Here is the code:(updated)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#from subprocess import Popen
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

song = OMXPlayer('/home/pi/5Seconds.mp3')

try:
   print ("Pir Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("Ready")
   active = False

   while  True:
       time.sleep(2)
       if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Motion detected")
       if not active:
            active = True
            print("Music started")
            song.play()
            time.sleep(10)

    elif active:
        print("No motion detected, stop the music")
        song.pause()
        song.can_control(song)
        active = False

    if active and song.poll() != None:  # detect completion to allow another start
        print("Music finished")
        active = False


except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print ("Quit")
   GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: is it because `song.quit()` unloads the OMXPlayer? Is there any other method to stop the song?

Comment: also you can go with `if` `else` instead of `if` & `if` in your condition check.

Comment: but I need to loop the entire code

Comment: else is throwing a syntax error :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original code, try the following, I have made a few minor changes to the way your script works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7 
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

song_path = '/home/pi/Hillsong.mp3'

try:
    print ("Pir Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Ready")
    active = False

    while  True:
        if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
            print("Motion detected")
            if not active:
                active = True
                print("Music started")
                omxp = Popen(['omxplayer', song_path])
        elif active:
            print("No motion detected, stop the music")
            omxp.terminate()
            active = False

        if active and omxp.poll() != None:  # detect completion to allow another start
            print("Music finished")
            active = False

        time.sleep(5)

 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print ("Quit")
     GPIO.cleanup()
```

Note:

1. `while True` means loop forever, as such the `time.sleep(10)` following it would never be executed.
2. `while False` will never execute what is inside it, so `omxp.terminate()` would never be executed.
3. Use a variable `active` to indicate if the player is running to avoid multiple starts.

I do not have a Pi to hand so it has not been tested.

Comment: I will test it and report it back

Comment: I tested it but it does the same thing what my previous code does it repeats the song if the motion is detected more than once. There are only two issues left to solve Sir. One is the ssh becoming unresponsive after the script exits and second is the loop to go back again

Comment: I've tried simulating the code and it seems to work ok for me. I have added some print statements to help you see what is actually happening.

Comment: Sir the error is it doesn't kill the player it shows the message that no motion detected

Comment: Its working now  it was the player that was faulty thank you plus i imported subprocess to kill the task

Comment: Sir omxp.poll() doesn't work because of the wrapper :-http://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/